# Java 1.8 is compatible for BO4.0 SP9?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

Is Java 1.8 is compatible with BO4.0 SP9? When I am trying to open the BI launchpad - "Cannot launch Java report panel, please make sure you have installed Java Virtual Machine" error is displaying,
In BO server jre1.8_111 and JDK 1.8_111 are installed

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PAM](https://www.sap.com/documents/2016/06/ccc11ce6-747c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html), BI4.0 is supported with JRE 6-8.
Few things to note:

- The version of the JRE/JDK on the server is irrelevant.  A JRE must be installed on the client in order to use the WebI Java panel.
- The bitness of the JRE must match the browser.  If you are using 64-bit IE, then you will need a 64-bit JRE.
- Newer versions of Chrome and (I believe) Firefox do not support Java at all.

Comment: Chrome will not work. But Firefox still support Java Applets. The reference browser is Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Firefox began dropping support for NPAPI plugins with version 52.

Comment: We support only Firefox ESR 45 currently.